# Way to avoid layout file naming conflict among multiple Android projects

Tags: android

Currently, I have an Android project, consists of 1 main project, and multiple library projects.

Just that recently, I realize that if there is same layout filename among main project and library project, bad thing can happen.

```
third-party-library-project
    - res
        - layout
            - actionbar_custom_view_done_discard.xml
main-project
    - res
        - layout
            - actionbar_custom_view_done_discard.xml
```

So, if in `third-party-library-project`, if you are having line of code in its activity,

```
final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_done_discard, null);
```

### Error stack trace caused by layout file naming conflict

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.yccheok.jstock.gui/group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity.initActionBar(LockPatternActivity.java:356)
    at group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity.onCreate(LockPatternActivity.java:347)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010137 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1892)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:614)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
    ... 28 more
```

---

If I change the layout XML file in `third-party-library-project` to `actionbar_custom_view_done_discard1.xml`, the runtime error will gone.

This is not an issues, if the number of library projects is small. Conflict can be solved easily with simple renaming. However, when comes across huge number of library projects, what is a robust way, or strategy to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library projects need to ensure that their resource names will be distinctive and not collide with other library projects, such as by applying a prefix to those resource names.

Note that apparently [the new Gradle-based build system supports resource subdirectories](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018). I have not yet experimented with this, but if the subdirectory names form part of the resource ID, then putting your resources in a distinctive subdirectory would help to keep the resource IDs distinct (at least for non-`values` resources).

Comment: With the use of the AndroidX appcompat libraries, do we need to avoid layout, drawable, and attr name collisions with everything in their resource files? Google didn't use any prefixes to distinguish their stuff, although I suppose the risk of collisions may be worth it since their attributes will usually be 90% of what's used in a typical project.

Comment: @Tenfour04: I think they are still working on having each library have an independent resource namespace (so collisions would not be possible, except for resources specifically declared as being public). So, ideally, only carefully redefine existing library resources. The problem in this question is not so much that the app reused a resource ID, but that it reused it for some other incompatible purpose.

Comment: I think android team solve half of the problem, in my java/kotlin code pick the correct resource buy when using "<include layout="@layout/same_name_with_other_module" />" pick the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest renaming your project resource file and not the 3rd party file in your first example since you may want to pull changes from the 3rd party library project again. Secondly I would suggest not using too many 3rd party library projects to begin with. From my experience the Android build system still has lots of hiccups with library projects. Things like BuildConfig.DEBUG do not work and I've had issues with library projects that contain jar file dependencies breaking the ability to run unit tests through Android instrumentation. There are tons of other bugs as well, most of them probably fairly obscure but enough of an issue that I don't suggest using library projects any more than absolutely necessary.

Comment: I had been using 9 project libraries. There is some problem in between. All my faced problem can be solved, although it is something not easy...